# OpenIdButton's extension returns null

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

Following is my code written in vb.net.

> Protected Sub OpenIdButton3_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdEventArgs) Handles OpenIdButton3.LoggedIn
>
> OpenIdButton3.Visible = False
>
> Dim profile As ClaimsResponse = e.Response.GetExtension(Of ClaimsResponse)()
>
> Dim email As String = profile.Email
>
> MsgBox(email)
>
> End Sub

But Line

> Dim email As String = profile.Email

is giving a following error.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have read relevant documentation on this and I have implemented AXFetchAsSregTransform in webconfig. Following is the block that shows the same.

> 

```
<sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
  <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
</sectionGroup>
```

>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>

```
<openid>

  <relyingParty>
```

```
      <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />

    </behaviors>

  </relyingParty>

</openid>
```

</dotNetOpenAuth>

Even then, I seems to get null value. I am getting authentication from Google.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Posting it here so others who face the same issue can be helped.

> 'Global Declaration - If you declare them locally, for some reason, they don't seems to work
>
> > > > Dim relyingParty As New OpenIdRelyingParty
> > > >
> > > > Dim authResponse As IAuthenticationResponse

After Declaring this create a button on your web form which will allow user to log onto Google. And a lable that will show the email id of the user who has logged in.

> 'Put following code on the Page load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim googleAppsDiscovery As New HostMetaDiscoveryService() With {.UseGoogleHostedHostMeta = True}
    relyingParty.DiscoveryServices.Insert(0, googleAppsDiscovery)

    authResponse = relyingParty.GetResponse()

    If authResponse IsNot Nothing Then
        If authResponse.Status = AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated Then
            Dim fetch As FetchResponse = authResponse.GetExtension(Of FetchResponse)()
            If fetch IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Save user details in session variables
                'Dim temp As [String]() = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email).ToString().Split("@"c)
                Dim temp As String = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email).ToString()
                If temp IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim userName As String = temp
                    Label1.Text = "You are logged in as : " & userName
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Put following code in the click event of button

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim currentPageURL As String = curPageURL.ToString

    Dim urlRealm As New Uri(currentPageURL)
    Dim urlReturn As New Uri(currentPageURL)

    Dim rm As Realm = New Realm(urlRealm)
    Dim gIdentifier As String = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"

    Dim request As IAuthenticationRequest = relyingParty.CreateRequest(gIdentifier, urlRealm, urlReturn)

    Dim fetch As New FetchRequest

    fetch.Attributes.Add(New AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email, True))
    request.AddExtension(fetch)

    request.RedirectToProvider()
End Sub
```

Add following two function to get the your current URL

```
Function curPageURL() As String
    Dim s, protocol, port As String

    If Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") = "on" Then
        s = "s"
    Else
        s = ""
    End If

    protocol = strLeft(LCase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PROTOCOL")), "/") & s

    If Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT") = "80" Then
        port = ""
    Else
        port = ":" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")
    End If

    curPageURL = protocol & "://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & _
          port & Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
End Function

Function strLeft(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As String
    strLeft = Left(str1, InStr(str1, str2) - 1)
End Function
```

And you are done.